# Identificar el nombre de la PC que se conecto al escritorio remoto de Windows

Tags: c#, vb.net, cuenta-usuario

Buen día, tengo un servidor con sistema Operativo windows 7, tengo configurado para que otras PC se conecten al escritorio remoto. Quiero saber que PC se conectan, el nombre del usuario no es mi problema ya que conseguí como hacerlo.Un ejemplo: Desde el Servidor vamos al Administrador de Tares -->Solapa Usuario, notaran que hay una columna que dice "Nombre del cliente", este es el nombre que yo nesecito.Muchas Gracias

Comment: pero como consigues con codigo c# el usuario que se conecta por remote desktop ? mencionas un ejemplo, pero esto no es desde codigo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo puedes obtener utilizando este código

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientName");
```

Comment: Si me Funciona Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que esté utilizando servicios de *Terminal Server* y escritorio remoto, puede comprobar la variable de entorno *CLIENTNAME*, para recuperar el nombre de la máquina cliente, aunque algunas personas denuncien problemas con él.

Puede obtener el valor con `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`, por ejemplo:

```
var clientName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME");
```

Para un método basado en API, marque la forma preferida de obtener el nombre del cliente desde la sesión de *Terminal Server* que muestra cómo usar *WMI* o la API de *Terminal Services* para recuperar el nombre del cliente.

Parece que la biblioteca de *Cassia* encapsula la API de *Terminal Server*. Puede obtener el nombre del cliente con:

```
TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.ClientName
```

Otro subproceso del sistema operativo muestra cómo recuperar el nombre de cliente de la sesión actual o los nombres de cliente de todas las sesiones.

Comment: Ok, Funciona correctamente gracias

Comment: De nada, siempre  a la orden.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado por favor marca la respuesta como correcta. Así ayudamos a otras personas!  Gracias de antemano.